# Redirect to controller throws "Unfortunately, something went wrong."

Tags: shopware

I have installed this plugin https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-storefront-controller in development-template but when i run this and tried to clear cart it redirect to url and shows error "Unfortunately, something went wrong."

**In logs i have found below error**

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Exception\InvalidRouteScopeException:
>   "Invalid route scope for route frontend.checkout.clearCart." at
>   /var/www/html/shopware6/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Framework/Routing/RouteScopeListener.php
>   line 93 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Exception\InvalidRouteScopeException(code:
>   0): Invalid route scope for route frontend.checkout.clearCart. at
>   /var/www/html/shopware6/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Framework/Routing/RouteScopeListener.php:93)"}
>   []

However this works fine in installer setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a route scope to your controller. This is mandatory since a few weeks ago, but it seems as the example was not changed according to this.

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/getting-started/recent-updates#routescope-details

It should be enough to add the routescope-annotation to the controller: 
https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-storefront-controller/blob/master/src/Storefront/Controller/ClearCartController.php#L23

Just add this to the annotation:

```
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
```

And add the route scope:

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
```

I will prepare a pull-request which should fix it.

Comment: The PR that should fix this issue: https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-storefront-controller/pull/1